# Linq Entity Framework update query

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I want to convert a SQL query to an ADO.NET Entity Framework LINQ query. I'm working with MySQL.

SQL:

```
Update Not As n 
Inner Join user As a 
On a.UserId = n.Not_UserId  
Set Not_Checked='0' 
Where n.Not_Checked='1' 
And n.Not_UserId='" + Not_UserId + "'
```

LINQ:

```
var n5 = from u in db.user
         join n in db.not
         on u.UserId equals n.Not_UserId
         where n.Not_Checked==1 && n.Not_UserId==4
         select new
         {
               u,
               n
         };
```

I want to update the value of `n`. I've tried `n5.n` but it didn't work. How to update `n` using LINQ EF?

Comment: _I try to n5.n but it doesn't work_ Could you explain?

Comment: I tried "n5.n.Not_Checked" but it doesn't work.I want to reach "Not_Checked" field under the "db.not" table.If I reach to this fied,I want to update.

Comment: @Conrad... Quite right... I had my vb.net hat on... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```cs
foreach (var x in n5.ToList())
{
    x.n.Not_Checked = 0;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Note that `n5` is an `IQueryable`, so you have to loop through to get to the element(s), or do `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first one.